# automatically updating a label objective-c without clicking a button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have 4 labels, 3 are editable with one label that cant be edited and one float which is the sum of the 3 editable labels.  Whats the easiest way to get the uneditable label to update automatically with the summed value of the other labels as the user edits them? (i dont want the user to have to click a button after the user has edited the labels) I know i'll probably be using bindings but your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your three editable labels are actually "text fields", designate some object (probably your view controller) as a delegate and then respond to this [NSControlTextEditingDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSControlTextEditingDelegate) method:

[`- control:shouldEndTextEditing:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSControlTextEditingDelegate/control%3atextShouldEndEditing%3a)

When the user tabs or exits the editable text field, you'll catch that event via the protocol method and then you can update that non-editable text field (which you've set to an outlet in your view controller, right?).

Or, you can use bindings, yes.  :-)